# Как работает ссылка?

Tags: c++, массивы, ссылки

Друзья, помогите джуну в C++!
Когда пишем

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

То мы создаем указатель на первый символ в этой строке?
Тогда почему в `cout << str;` выводится вся строка, а не адрес первого символа?

Comment: Потому что [нуль-терминированная строка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нуль-терминированная_строка). Операция вывода просто выводит все символы начиная с указанного адреса, пока не встретит символ с кодом 0.

Comment: хм, интересно! Спасибо, вроде что-то начинает проясняться.

Comment: А почему вы убрали ответ как принятый?

Comment: Случайно нажал галочку на другом)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что существует перегруженная версия оператора `<<` для `char *` которая интерпретирует указатель на `char` как [строку в стиле C](http://cppstudio.com/post/9567/).

Если вы хотите вывести на печать адрес первого элемента массива, то нужно воспользоваться версией `<<`, которая не интерпретирует операнд как строку:

```
std::cout << (void *) str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Для  `char*` возможно определить operator `<<` так, чтобы в поток вводить все символы:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const char* p)
{
    while (*p != '\0')
        os << *p++;
    return os;
}
```

в стандарте такое определение какраз и существует, но для других типов это невозможно, потому что  в таком случаи нужно передать еше и размер, так как  у других типов массив не ограничен специальным символом, но размер не можем передать, постольку поскольку этот оператор имеет 2 аргумента ("третий лишный").

Для эксперимента, вы можете определить свою версию, если уверены, что ваш указатель укажет на строку с более чем двух символов

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const char* p)
{
    while (*(p + 2) != '\0')
        os << *p++;
    return os;
}

int main()
{   
   const char* str= "hello";  //Да, именно  const char*, а не  char*  
   cout << str; // выдаст "hel", т.е. на 2 символа меньше
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я привел упрощенные варианты, на самом деле  нужно обрабатывать исключительные случаи, например такие как  исключение обработки нулевого указателья...